# MongoDB query Mixed Type field with $in

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to query a `Mixed Type` field with `$in` but it doesn't seem to be working:

`db.acts.find({user: { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")] } }})`

But I have a user with field of `_id` with a value of `ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")`

Why is it not working ?

Comment: Did you confirm it works if you remove the $in:[] and find just the single ObjectID

Comment: Try db.acts.find({"user._id": { $in: [ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")] }) instead.

Comment: @JamesWahlin It works with MongoDB 3.0.2, whereas the OP query does not return anything. Have you an explanation for that  unexpected behavior ?

Comment: That works ... but why ?!? Is there something obvious I cannot see ? As of my myself, I would have thought both should work...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I agree.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but the original syntax may be invalid (in which case mongod should probably produce an error). Using the "user: { }" match syntax means we are looking to match the entire document. I am not sure what using $in within this context means though can see the argument for this working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `{field: <value>}` notation to match an embedded document, `<value>` is the **document to match**. Not a **document query**.

In other words, when you write:

```
{user: { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")] }}}
```

MongoDB will try to find an *exact* match to the document `{ $in: [ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")] }` (literally!) in the field `_id`.

You can see that by looking at the parsed query using `explain`:

```
> db.test.find({user: { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")] }}}).explain().queryPlanner.parsedQuery
{
    "user" : {
        "$eq" : {
            "_id" : {
                "$in" : [
                    ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Given your needs, you have to rewrite your query using the dot-notation instead:

```
{"user._id": { $in: [ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")] }}
```

Please note however this is subtlety different from your initial query, as this will match any embedded document *having* an id in the given array. It will not search for an *exact* match (i.e.: an embedded document *containing only* an id). If you really need that later, using `$or` is the solution:

```
{$or: [{user: {_id: ObjectId("555b63c6b9aaf6d80aecccc3")}},
       {user: {_id: ... }},
       {user: {_id: ... }}
      ]}
```